# PHP imagepng image cannot be displayed contains errors

Tags: php, image

I have a class in StrToImg.php which makes an image from a string:

```
class StrToImg
{
    public function show($img_str = '')
    {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $im = imagecreate(100, 30);
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
        imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $img_str, $textcolor);
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}
```

In my view.php I have this:

```
<?php 
$img = new StrToImg();
$img->show('Hello'); 
?>
```

But it tells me "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

If I add this to StrToImg.php:

```
$img = new StrToImg();
$img->show('Hello');
```

and simply load this class file from the view.php:

```
<img src="<?php echo StrToImg.php' ?>" />
```

It shown the image correctly.

What can be wrong with the view.php

Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the header() line and see if any non-image-text is output. Maybe there's some error or notice that's getting thrown?

Comment: I did, it shows a gray icon, it's an empty image, no erros

Comment: Is the empty page the one with <img> or the actual source when you load StrToImg.php directly in the browser?

Comment: it's the one with the <img>. By empty I meant the areas where the image block should be is empty. The page as a whole loads fine with other stuff. And if I copy the direct path to the image class, the whole page, the image is empty.

Comment: Try opening the source of your <img> tag in a separate tab, and please do comment out the `header()` line marking the content type as `image/png`.

Comment: I commented out the header line, uncommented it, opened the page source of StrToImg.php and it's empty, the header doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167009/discussion-between-arik-and-linuxoid).